# Retrieve Facebook User ID (or anything unique) without Authentication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is there anyway to get the Facebook ID of a user without forcing them to authenticate? I'm trying to create an app page where the user can only add an answer to a poll once, so I need to be able to identify viewers by some kind of unique identifier.

My preference would be to not force them to log in. I think it's bad UX to add 2 extra steps just so I can make sure a facebook user on a facebook page is unique. I don't need any permissions to their profile/etc.

BTW, I've seen similar questions though nothing current or close enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No possibility if you don't make your user log in, for security reasons, the user has to be aware you are collecting information about him, it's also why there is a login.

With the PHP SDK, to get the id after login:

```
$userId = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: I've figured out how to get the user ids, just wondering if there's a way to uniquely identify a user without forcing them to give me authorization.

Comment: Related to Facebook user, no. If you need unique identification, you might go for ip and cookie... Trying to know their Facebook id without permissions doesn't seems very legit...

Comment: Yeah, I think tracking by IP is more intrusive and cookies won't keep the user unique. I'll have to figure something else out